# How does strlen works in this case?

Tags: c, escaping, c-strings, string-literals, strlen

See the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%lu",strlen("\\n"));
}
```

I know that the output would be `2` but confused whether `\\` would be the first character taken into account and then `n` or `\` would be the first count and `\n` would be the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*... But I am confused whether `\\` would be the first character taken into account and then `n` or `\` would be the first count and `\n` would be the second?*"

`"\\"` is the representation for the `'\'` character inside of a string literal.

Thus, The first character of the string literal `"\\n"` is `'\'` and `'n'` the second.

You can make an experiment by using `printf("\\n");`. The output would be `\n`, not `\(line feed)`.

Comment: It was a tie between you and MikeCAT. I did a toss and accepted your answer :)

Comment: @NirajRaut The `printf()` experiment is good, but he forgot to mention the difference to your second case scenario. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> simple-escape-sequence: one of

```
\' \" \? \\
\a \b \f \n \r \t \v
```

and

> 3 The single-quote ', the double-quote ", the question-mark ?, **the
>   backslash **, and arbitrary integer values are representable according
>   to the following table of escape sequences:

```
single quote ' \'
double quote " \"
question mark ? \?
backslash \ \\
octal character \octal digits
hexadecimal character \x hexadecimal digits
```

Thus this string literal `"\\n"` contains `backslash` and the character `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s","\\n");
}
```

`\n` will be printed. This means that the first character is `\\` (an escape sequence that is converted to `\`) and the second character is `n`.

Answer (score 0):

`"\\n"` is parsed from left to right.  `"\\"` is the escape sequence for a backslash (a single `\`).  `"n"`, in this case, is just an `"n"` and not `"\n"`.  Hence, two characters `return`ed by `strlen`.